# Any particular reason why this piece of code doesn't work? I can't seem the figure out the issue

Tags: php, html, mysql

The goal of this page is to check the tags table in my database and generate unordered list with the tag name and tag image of every row. The following code allows me to do that perfectly :

```
<?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tags";

                echo "<ul id='ulTags'>";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo '<div class="imageContainerTags"><a href="specificTag.php?='.$row['tag'].'"><li class="listTags"><h1>'.$row['tag'].'</h1></li><img class="tagThumbnail" src="images/Tags/'.$row['path'] .'" alt="Random image" /></a></div>';
                    }
                echo "</ul>";
        ?>
```

However, I have decided to implement the possibility to delete a tag from the database if you have the permission. Every user has a permission and if you have a permission of 1, you should see a delete button under each image. This is the updated code featuring that functionality :

```
<?php
                $userId = $_SESSION['id'];

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tags";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM user where id='$userId'";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
                $getResult2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

                $userP = $getResult2['permission'];

                echo "<ul id='ulTags'>";
                if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && $userP == 1) {
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo '<div class="imageContainerTags"><a href="specificTag.php?='.$row['tag'].'"><li class="listTags"><h1>'.$row['tag'].'</h1></li><img class="tagThumbnail" src="images/Tags/'.$row['path'] .'" alt="Random image" /></a></div>';
                        echo "<form method='POST' action='".deleteTag($conn)."'>
                                            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>
                                            <input type='hidden' name='tag' value='".$row['tag']."'>
                                            <input type='hidden' name='path' value='".$row['path']."'>
                                            <button id='delTag' type='submit' name='tagDelete'>Delete Tag</button>
                            </form>";
                    }
                } else {
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo '<div class="imageContainerTags"><a href="specificTag.php?='.$row['tag'].'"><li class="listTags"><h1>'.$row['tag'].'</h1></li><img class="tagThumbnail" src="images/Tags/'.$row['path'] .'" alt="Random image" /></a></div>';
                    }
                };
                echo "</ul>";
        ?>
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be a problem with the code and it only echoes one tag and not all of them as it should do. The first piece of code echoed all the tags but that was before me trying to add a delete button. Any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: What is deleteTag($conn) ouptut?

Comment: It's inside an include file that deals with the logic for the tag delete and that file is included in the page so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid that it isn't the way to be handled, in action you must have a name of a PHP script, for example
<form method="POST" action="delete.php">

Comment: This is strange since I've done the same thing with deleting images and it works. My action points to a function in a PHP include page and it works just right.

Comment: if you put it like this. The deleteTag() function would be executed in the server before the user even seeing it. and it's output would be printed here action=".... ">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do to debug is to insert echoes at each part of the code to see where its getting derailed.

First inspect the output html page source to see that the tags are properly echoed (no html error).

I would place echo $result->num_rows  Just before the if else clause to see the total tags returned.

If there are multiple tags in the result and only one is displayed then I will see if that tag is the last or first tag in the returned result.

Check these to get started....

NB: Why don't you use consistent coding style?

```
    //One place you use

    $getResult2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2); // functional programming

    // another place you use 

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); // OOP programming

    // Stick to one style, preferably OOP
```

Comment: First of all, doing that helped me find the problem so thank you :) . Secondly, I'm quite new to back-end programming and I'm trying to learn procedural PHP and OOP PHP simultaneously which sometimes leads to that inconsistency. Frankly I'm currently avoiding OOP because It's kinda confusing for now even though I understand the benefits of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the if statement in your code with this.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && $userP == 1) {
                    while ($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo '<div class="imageContainerTags"><a href="specificTag.php?='.$row2['tag'].'"><li class="listTags"><h1>'.$row2['tag'].'</h1></li><img class="tagThumbnail" src="images/Tags/'.$row2['path'] .'" alt="Random image" /></a></div>';
                        echo "<form method='POST' action='".deleteTag($conn)."'>
                                            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row2['id']."'>
                                            <input type='hidden' name='tag' value='".$row2['tag']."'>
                                            <input type='hidden' name='path' value='".$row2['path']."'>
                                            <button id='delTag' type='submit' name='tagDelete'>Delete Tag</button>
                            </form>";
                    }
                } else {
                    while ($row2 = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo '<div class="imageContainerTags"><a href="specificTag.php?='.$row2['tag'].'"><li class="listTags"><h1>'.$row2['tag'].'</h1></li><img class="tagThumbnail" src="images/Tags/'.$row2['path'] .'" alt="Random image" /></a></div>';
                    }
                };
```

Comment: The end result is the same. Only the first tag is getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side programming language, HTML forms are client side. 
here deleteTag() is a PHP function, it has no effect at the time when the form is submitted at the client.

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='delete.php'>
```

where delete.php have the logic necessary to handle deletion